# How to iterate loop in JQuery to add dynamic elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select in HTML page on which I am doing an ajax call as soon as it is changed.Below is the response i get from AJAX Call

```
{_id: {$oid: "59d3d498e8cc691345b093d4"}, user_id: "59b6678910e8f540e732314d",…}
created: "21-09-2017"
user_id: "59b6678910e8f540e732314d"
friend_id: "59c403a16ebded1314002588"
options: {,…}
1: {time: "time1", brand: "brand1", contents: "content1", quantity: "20ml",…}
2: {time: "time2", brand: "brand2", contents: "content2", quantity: "20ml",…}
querystatus: true
referred_friend: "Mr. Aakash"
session_id: "CuBrGwXNdJHPUshB"
_id:{$oid: "59d3d498e8cc691345b093d4"}
    $oid: "59d3d498e8cc691345b093d4"
```

What I am trying to achieve is I am trying to display this dynamically in JQuery first to generate HTML data then append in HTML.

The problem is there is an object named options which has 2 arrays in it. This depends it might be 1 OR 2 OR None.

But in short what i want to do is i want each and every data displayed using a looping structure

I tried this code:

```
$.each(resp, function(key, value)
    {
        console.log( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );
    });
```

This displays data accurately of variables that don't have a nested object in themselves but for variables like options in response, it shows `object object` i also want to access data inside it.

Where is my logic failing.

Comment: Which part of the response are you trying to create html and append to the select element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '", value);
});
```

This should print the object
If you want to access property of an object the

```
value.<property name>
```